# What does dd stand for?

Tags: dd, command-names

I know very well what the command does, but `man dd`, `info dd` tell me: 'Convert and copy a file', as does [GNU Coreutils](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/dd.html).

Google says its an abbreviation of everything between medicine and bad webchat slang; except someone saying it means 'data destroyer', something used in PC forensics - I'd be horrified if my dd destroyed *my* data!

Any insight? :-)

---

**Update**: Of course I had to check [the jargon file](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/dd.html):

> The Unix dd(1) was designed with a
>   weird, distinctly non-Unixy keyword
>   option syntax reminiscent of IBM
>   System/360 JCL (which had an elaborate
>   DD ‘Dataset Definition’ specification
>   for I/O devices)

Still sounds pretty ambiguous, but then it says:

> though the command filled a need, the interface design was clearly a prank.

Heh :-)

Comment: `dd` is particularly good at destroying data if you aren't careful.  "Data Destroyer" is not really a misnomer.

Comment: Cross reference: http://askubuntu.com/a/645765/25036 (2015-07-08) under _What does the command name “dd” stand for?_

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Wikipedia ([dd)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)) asserts it was named after **IBM JCL** command *DD* which stands for *Data Definition*. I always thought it would mean *data duplicate*, though.

Comment: And Wikipedia is not really a reliable reference, as this goes to show.

Comment: It also says `It is jokingly said to stand for "disk destroyer", "data destroyer", or "delete data"` - cross referencing this with the Jargon file clicks a switch, I believe this is the answer we're looking for!

Comment: I always thought it was data duplicate too.

Comment: Oh, Wikipedia doesn't even *assert* anything, it just says (which is probably violating WP:NOR) "is most likely inspired from[sic] DD".

Comment: I've heard that it came from JCL from some sysadmin old-timers.  See the documentation for DD to compare: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/basics/topic/com.ibm.zos.zjcl/zjclc_jclDDstmt.htm

Comment: good call @jsbillings, I guess 'Description' and 'Definition' was synonymous then. Totally valid considering the terms I've come across in legacy systems.

Comment: It was definitely Dataset Definition. Dataset was the IBM term for File. In JCL you needed to write a DD record to define the file that you wanted to use and give a 2 character unit number code to reference in your Open statements.

Comment: //SYSUT1#3 DD DISP=(SHR,KEEP),DSN=DDAG.D1006Y00.SHT.APPLTN.NAMES ...(some real JCL, with a real 'IBM' DD :) ..There is no way it is relatd to the nix 'dd' ..BTW, the '//' is not a comment indicator

Comment: Can you add a reference?

Comment: On the topic of the cc/dd name: [*Spurious.  dd was always named after JCL dd cards.*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.folklore.computers/HAWoZ8g-xYk) -- Dennis Ritchie (alt.folklore.computers, 2004)

Answer (score 48):

Though the “best answer” was given, [this site states otherwise](http://www.roesler-ac.de/wolfram/acro/credits.htm#1):

> Actually, it stands for ‘Copy and
>   Convert’ and was renamed to `dd` only
>   because `cc` was reserved for the C
>   compiler! This is the authentic
>   information I got from the man pages
>   of our Unix-V7 on our university PDP
>   11.

Original mail at `comp.unix.misc`(usenet): [The Unix Acronym List](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.misc/LbLTa00Jnvg)

Comment: But the postings go on to say: `He's not sure if it was ever actually called cc in UNIX, but he is _certain_ that the name dd comes from the jcl dd command (so does the wreched syntax).`

Comment: This is proving quite an investigation. 'Copy and Convert' describe's dd's function nicely! Some systems did have cc as the 'C-Compiler', and light-bulb moment: does gcc stand for 'GNU C Compiler'? :-) Interesting.

Comment: There is a very simple issue involved here.  'DD' is from IBM's JCL and 'dd' is from UNIX .. one is Upper-case, the other Lower-case where case ma.ttered... IBM didn't really have much to do with UNIX and vice-versa... and DD/dd did different things... So, to me, *anything other than this* is a possibility

Comment: @invert gcc stands for `GNU Compiler Collection`, but knowing GNU and their weird obsession with acronyms, it probably stands for both..

Comment: I see no such claim in the V7 nor PWB Unix man pages, both of which can be found on TUHS for instance, that sounds a bit like Urban myth.

Answer (score 14):

"dump data".  JCL is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes this does make sense, functionally, even if the origins say something else.

Comment: Probaby a backronym. https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Backronym

Comment: Disk Dump is correct. Back then it was normal to use DD to backup a hard drive partition to tape. Most of the other options were related to things that people wanted to do with tapes, such as convert EBCDIC to ASCII.

Comment: *JCL is irrelevant* -- that depends on the question being asked.  One question is the historical origin, in which case JCL is probably relevant.  Another question is the most clever and fitting backronym one can imagine for modern `dd` usage, in which case this answer might be more appropriate.  I'm not actually sure which the OP is asking.

Comment: It makes a great deal of sense, and is therefore almost certainly wrong. Lexicography is no task for amateurs.

Comment: @Rob : I believe Jürgen A. Erhard is incorrect, based on the evidence of mr.spuratic's cited source.  We aren't likely to get a more authoritative source than that of one of the key creators of Unix.

Comment: "data dump" on Perl, e.g. https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump and related.

Comment: I've always been told it meant *Dump Data*, being a unix command to dump disk files to magnetic tape (*long ago pre in pre-Linux days when sending data by tape was still common*). That's what I was told back at uni (*or at least my memory of it*), and I see no connection at all with the IBM  JCL DD .. as its descriptive in MVS JCL only, and doesn't at all relate to COPY etc; as how its used [in JCL] will be defined elsewhere in the JCL, with the DD being *descriptive* only (links JCL references to an actual DSN; in IBM/MVS terms)

Answer (score 2):

Someone was questioning whether the UNIX (and Linux) dd command actually had any relationship to the IBM JCL dd command.  I would argue that it DID and that it had a direct bearing on the choice of the name, and here is the reason.

"Way back" in the eighties and before, AT&T had operational support systems, particularly billing systems, that ran on equipment other than their own research systems.  In particular, things like long distance billing reports and other artifacts that needed to be transferred between mainframe computer systems and other systems had to have a mechanism.

In the UNIX way of doing things, transferring files - or any "objects" could be done a bit or a byte at a time, without regard to content or anything else.  The dd command had provisions for transferring those bits and bytes, and doing things like code set conversion between EBCDIC and ASCII, copying tape backups between diverse media types, and so forth.

Today, we can do things with this fairly ancient command and perform tasks such as creating bootable media on CD, DVD, small form factor USB sticks, and who knows what next, because the tool can simply transfer information, regardless of content.  The dd command, in this respect, is one of the most useful commands in the UNIX and Linux arsenal.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely dd is "copy and convert", as we have the "command line flag" conv (convert flags) with noerror, notrunc, sync, etc...

"Conv" has to mean "convert"!

```
dd if=<flag> of=<flag> conv=<flags> bs=<flag>
```

History told makes sense, the name “cc” was taken (by c compiler) therefore "copy and convert" was named dd, and later people remembered as "disk/data dump".

It's not POSIX, its JCL and this explains the syntax and the use of "command line flags" instead of parameters/arguments.

Comment: this is not true according to Dennis Ritchie: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6804/what-does-dd-stand-for/670220#comment408440_6805

Comment: What is a JCL dd card? - The JCL documentation shows dd as a completely different command: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos-basic-skills?topic=concepts-jcl-statements-what-does-dd-statement-do

Comment: I was referring specifically to the assertion that "cc was taken by the C compiler, so it became dd". maybe I just misread and you were trying to say that that's _not_ true? I'm having a little trouble reading your answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).