# Why does the tr command not read from file?

Tags: history, tr

I looked up a Unix book, the man and the wikipedia page for `tr` but could not find a reason why it was designed/implemented in such way that it does not read from file but strictly only from the standard input. For instance, tools such as `wc`, `grep`, `sed`, and `awk` all will happily read input from file if provided or from standard input. Was/Is there a compelling reason to design `tr` this way?

Comment: It was not coded that way, and life goes on... I suspect it must be due being another time with machines with severe memory restrictions, and tr is *old*. Unix utilities also were designed by several people, and well there are several inconsistencies and duplication of functionality across utilities.

Comment: Agreed with most of what you said but still... tr just comes across as a single odd such command. I can't think of any other similar command that has this kind of behavior.

Comment: Not sure as to the reason, but you could redirect `standard input < -` to get `tr` to act on a file, e.g. `tr "this text" "to this text" < some_file.txt` .

Comment: just to point out: this question has been flagged as primarily opinion-based but IMHO it shouldn't be closed; we've had questions similar to this on why things are implemented in whatever way that have very valid answers. see for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6804/what-does-dd-stand-for or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93773/why-is-sort-o-useful

Comment: It is now out of the review queue, but still sitting perilously on 4 close votes - if it does get the last one, please ping me here so I can vote to reopen.

Comment: @strugee I disagree.  Yes, us speculating sure are just opinion... but since there may still be people out there who actually *know* - or remember reading/hearing a first-hand account - it *is* a question it may be possible to answer.  1970 isn't that long ago.

Comment: _Unix_ inherited `tr` from _Multics_ as a derivative of _PL/1_ `translate` built-in function, which in turn was a generalization of a `TR` command in _System/360_ architecture (see [IBM System-360 Green Card](http://weblog.ceicher.com/archives/2006/12/ibm_system360_green_card.html)). Worth noting that _QNX_ implementation could actually read from a file [via `-r`](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/dv/hats/cats/stations/qnxman/tr.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [UNIX philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Eric_Raymond.E2.80.99s_17_Unix_Rules) advocates for "small, sharp tools", so the answer is that reading from a file would be bloat contrary to the UNIX philosophy. As to why `wc`, `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, etc do read from files, the answer is that they all have features that require more than one input or input selection or otherwise require direct access to the files. As `tr` is not commonly used for those reasons you are left with one of the following forms to meet your needs;

```
tr ... < file
tr ... < file > file2
tr ... < file | sponge file
```