# Copying a tree with modes

Tags: file-copy, tree

Suppose my build script creates something like:

```
build
├── [drwxr-xr-x pskocik  pskocik ]  bin
│   └── [-rwxr-xr-x pskocik  pskocik ]  FOO_bin
├── [drwxr-xr-x pskocik  pskocik ]  include
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x pskocik  pskocik ]  FOO
│   │   ├── [-rw-r--r-- pskocik  pskocik ]  FOO_a.h
│   │   └── [-rw-r--r-- pskocik  pskocik ]  FOO_b.h
│   └── [-rw-r--r-- pskocik  pskocik ]  FOO.h
├── [drwxr-xr-x pskocik  pskocik ]  lib
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- pskocik  pskocik ]  libFOO.a
│   └── [-rwxr-xr-x pskocik  pskocik ]  libFOO.so
└── [drwxr-xr-x pskocik  pskocik ]  share
    └── [drwxr-xr-x pskocik  pskocik ]  man
        ├── [drwxr-xr-x pskocik  pskocik ]  man1
        │   └── [-rw-r--r-- pskocik  pskocik ]  FOO.1.gz
        └── [drwxr-xr-x pskocik  pskocik ]  man3
            └── [-rw-r--r-- pskocik  pskocik ]  FOO.3.gz

8 directories, 8 files
```

What's the best way to copy this, say into `/usr` or `/usr/local`, so that

- files get reowned to root:root
- file modes stay untouched
- the same applies to directory nodes unless (optional) they already existed (in which case their ownerships and modes remain the same)

?

Answer (score 2):

Use rsync.

```
rsync -rltpDvh --chown root:root build/ /usr/
```

That means:

- `r`: Recursive
- `l`: Copy links
- `t`: Preserve timestamps
- `p`: Preserve permissions
- `D`: `--devices`
- `v`: Verbose
- `h`: Human readable progress

If you don't have it installed, use your package management first to install this wonderful tool :)

**Related Stuff:**

- [What is the difference between `dd`, `cp` and `rsync`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/338834/34720)

Comment: This rewrites the the modes in directory nodes, but otherwise it seems to work OK.

Comment: What modes are you talking about? Special permisson bits? This was by default on rsync 2.6.7 and older but it was changed - https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync - If you are talking about ACSs and Xattrs, you will have to add `-A` and `-X`options :)

Comment: Here's my test script https://pastebin.com/MGvUP9Fb  and here's a sample output https://pastebin.com/nFZYQ70f . As you can see, the mode of the preexisting directory at the destination gets changed after the rsync operation.

Comment: I dont know how it would behave with the `archive` option(`-a`that implies `-rlptgoD`), that's why i broke down into `-rltpDv` and removed the group and ownership options. what about if you use `rsync -avh --chown root:root build/ /usr/` ?